# Multiple Ace Editor content returns only one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ace-editor

I have implemented two ACE editors on my single page. The first editor:

```
$('#custom_css').val(custom_css_editor.getSession().getValue());
```

returns all the codes I've typed, but unfortunately the other editor:

```
$('#custom_script').val(custom_js_editor.getSession().getValue());
```

returns only one line. What do you think is the cause of such glitch?

Here's what I want to show up:

[image: multiple ACE editors]

Here are the codes I have:

```js
var custom_css_editor = ace.edit("custom_css_editor", {
  theme: "ace/theme/twilight",
  mode: "ace/mode/css",
  maxLines: 10
});
var custom_js_editor = ace.edit("custom_js_editor", {
  theme: "ace/theme/twilight",
  mode: "ace/mode/javascript",
  maxLines: 10
});

document.querySelector('#custom_css_editor .ace_text-input')
  .setAttribute('name', 'custom_css');
document.querySelector('#custom_css_editor .ace_text-input')
  .setAttribute('id', 'custom_css');
document.querySelector('#custom_js_editor .ace_text-input')
  .setAttribute('name', 'custom_script');
document.querySelector('#custom_js_editor .ace_text-input')
  .setAttribute('id', 'custom_script');
  
custom_css_editor.session.on('change', function() {
  $('#custom_css').val(custom_css_editor.getValue());
});
$('#custom_css').val(custom_css_editor.session.getValue());
custom_js_editor.getSession().on('change', function() {
  $('#custom_script').val(custom_js_editor.getValue());
});
$('#custom_script').val(custom_js_editor.session.getValue());
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="lbl-input" for="custom_css">Custom CSS</label>
  <div id="custom_css_editor"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="lbl-input" for="custom_script">Custom Scripts</label>
  <div id="custom_js_editor"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.4/ace.js"></script>
```

Comment: hello, I see a `div` with `custom_css_editor` as *id* in your HTML code but, I don't see anything with *id* `custom_js_editor` there, so... is `document.querySelector('#custom_js_editor .ace_text-input')` really working?

Comment: I see both codes working, but I was curious why the second editor return only one line?

Comment: I think it's better if you edit the answer itself, adding the missing (html) code so it'll be easier for others to help you

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are modifying the value of textarea `.ace_text-input`. Changing dom inside editor usually breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i have to add `<input type="hidden" id="custom_css" value="" />` and `custom_script" value="" />` to render the full content of css and js editors, magic it worked!